# Extend an application to dual monitors

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, monitors

I have an application which runs on a single monitor. It has grids in that. Say for example if the application can hold 3 girds and there are 4 items to be placed, the 4th item should go to the second screen. 
Algo: Check for grid size
      if grid size is more than 3
           open the remaining in the second(dual) screen.

Please let me know how to go about this.

Comment: Why not just make the form wider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.screen.allscreens.aspx

```
void showOnMonitor(int showOnMonitor) 
{ 
  Screen[] sc; 
  sc = Screen.AllScreens; 
  //get all the screen width and heights 
  Form2 f = new Form2(); 
  f.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None; 
  f.Left = sc[showOnMonitor].Bounds.Width; 
  f.Top = sc[showOnMonitor].Bounds.Height; 
  f.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual; 
  f.Show(); 
}
```

Comment: Could you translate it to C# please? Thanks!

Comment: I suppose this just switches from 1 monitor to the other. What I need is to extend the form. I mean I have the form already running on the first screen. I want it to extend(maximize) it on to the second screen too.

Comment: Sorry, just remove that "function". With the System.Windows.Forms.Screen[] you should have all you need. Just look at the msdn article.

Comment: With the sc[showOnMonitor].Bounds.Width you can set the size of your form to the width of screen1.width + screen2.width

Comment: Thanks.. It works. I was setting FormWindowState.Maximized to true. So it was not changing. I removed it and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Inspect type System.Windows.Forms.Screen.